# When condition not working properly - pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Code:

```py
Df1 = df.withColumn(
    "sales",
    when(col("sales").isNull(), 10)
    .when(col("sales") == 0, 7)
    .when(col("sales") > 5, 3)
    .when((col("sales") < 5) & (col("sales") != 0), 5)
    .when(col("ISM").isNull(), 50)
    .when((col("ISM").isNotNull()) & (col("ECR") != "MO"), 50)
    .when(
        (col("ISM").isNull())
        & (col("ECR") == "MO")
        & (col("SER") > 0)
        & (col("SER") <= 1),
        5,
    )
    .otherwise(col("sales")),
)
```

Issue:
conditions in line no  7 and 8 are not working correctly, in this order.

For ex: when we set sales to 5 if its between o and 5, the next condition is to override sales value if ISM is null; however...that doesn't happen and the values remains 5
same issue for line 8. Can you explain why the order is not being correctly executed

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

`when` are executed sequentially but the evaluation stops at the first one valid. At the very end, if none of the conditions are met, then you'll have the `otherwise` value.

Comment: Apart from when; what function can be used to achieve the desired results

Comment: you just need to fix the order of the `when`s. From the most important to the least. Basically the last one (with the `isNull` and other conditions) should come before the simple `isNull`.